# How to print the components data(input) and prediction(output) using classifier in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, classification, data-science, random-forest

I have a dataset which carries the author_id, language, text, author(bot or human) and gender(bot, male or female). I trained the classifier and got the accuracy. Now I need to print author_id, language, author and gender(which was predicted by the classifier).
How can I get all the data?

I searched alot but could not much about it as I am new to it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Y7v.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

i can give you an example ...

#input data

```
id = input('Enter your ID :')
author = input('bot or human :')
gender =input('male or female :')

print(id,author,gender)
```